# Как разместить фоновую картинку?

Tags: html, css, background, img, position

https://ibb.co/4VqLgcS - ссылка на картинку.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы на сайте она размещалась, так же как на макете, представленном выше. 
С помощью `position` не получается, т.к. вся картинка смещается вправо и появляется скролл по ширине.
Что сделать чтобы при выходе за экран она обрезалась?

Comment: Без исходного кода трудно чем-то вам помочь

Comment: С помощью `position: absolute`, а родителю задавайте `position: relative` и манипулируйте элементом, задавая ему top, left, right, bottom

Comment: такое чувство что никто из вас не прочитал вопрос и не посмотрел макет. Какой, извиняюсь, к черту код, если я не знаю что писать и от того спрашиваю вас? Неужели по макету не понятно что я хочу сделать?

Comment: По поводу position я также написал, что при его использовании картинка выходит за рамки страницы и появляется скролл по ширине, а мне нужно чтобы этого не было, чтобы можно было вынести этот кусок мяса за пределы экрана и он обрезался, как в figma. Если вы в ней работали, то вы знаете, что когда картинка выходит за фрейм, то та часть, которая за пределами фрейма, обрезается и становиться невидимой. Мне нужно сделать тоже самое только с помощью css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А это зависит от того, что вам нужно. Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен.
 Это варианты с картинкой:

```css
.block_one {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block_two {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

.block_two img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQoD4.jpg" alt="Дорогие друзья, с Рождеством, с Новым 2020 Годом!"></div>
<div class="block_one"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQoD4.jpg" alt="Дорогие друзья, с Рождеством, с Новым 2020 Годом!"></div>
<div class="block_two"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQoD4.jpg" alt="Дорогие друзья, с Рождеством, с Новым 2020 Годом!"></div>
```

А это варианты с фоном:

```css
.block {
margin: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQoD4.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.block_one {
  background-size: auto;
}

.block_two {
  background-size: cover;
}

.block_three {
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block_one"></div>
<div class="block block_two"></div>
<div class="block block_three"></div>
```